# Scrolling UITableView mess with gradient

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

I have a custom TableViewCell on my TableViewController.
The cell has a UIView that is turned into a gradient that displays black at the bottom and clear (transparent) color on the top of the UIView.

It looks fine when the app loads, but as I scroll, the gradient turns more and more black and the 'fading' itself becomes smaller and gets closer to the top of the UIView.

I do not know how to make it stay as it is when the app loads at first.

Here's my code:

```
let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
gradient.frame = cell.gradientView.bounds
let colour:UIColor = .black
gradient.colors = [colour.withAlphaComponent(0.0).cgColor,colour.cgColor]

cell.gradientView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code in awakeFromNib  not in cellForRow , as because of dequeuing the gradient is being added multiple times to the cell

```
   let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = cell.gradientView.bounds
    let colour:UIColor = .black
    gradient.colors = [colour.withAlphaComponent(0.0).cgColor,colour.cgColor]
    self.gradientView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
```